# For MS Access SQL, want to use EXCEPT in Access for three columns in table1 to 1 column in table 2

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I have 3 columns in table A. I am trying to design a query that will call out all the values (in the three columns) that do not apepar in the 1 column I have in table B. If it helps to make it more clear, table B is a list of currencies in ISO codes and table A is three columns of currencies being used, I am identifying all those values that are NOT using ISO codes to denote their currency.

Currently, I can't seem to get them all to match to the one column, so I made 2 more columns in table B so I can match them individually. My constraints are, I cannot change table A and I must do this in one query. What I got so far is below.

```
SELECT m.Currency1, i.ISO_Code, m.Currency2 , i.ISO_Code1, m.Currency3, i.ISO_Code2
FROM A AS m
LEFT JOIN B AS i 
ON m.Currency=i.ISO_Code
AND m.Currency2=i.ISO_Code1
AND m.Currency3=i.ISO_Code2

WHERE i.ISO_Code is NULL
OR i.ISO_Code1 is NULL
OR i.ISO_Code2 is NULL;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother making multiple columns in 'B'. I played with this in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/315a3/6) and got it to work.

Something like this:

`SELECT`
 `m.Currency1, i.ISO_Code,`
 `m.Currency2, j.ISO_Code AS ISO_Code1,`
  `m.Currency3, k.ISO_Code AS ISO_Code2`
`FROM A AS m`

`LEFT JOIN B as i`
`ON m.Currency1 = i.ISO_Code`

`LEFT JOIN B as j`
`ON m.Currency2 = j.ISO_Code`

`LEFT JOIN B as k`
`ON m.Currency3 = k.ISO_Code`

`WHERE`
`i.ISO_Code IS NULL OR`
`j.ISO_Code IS NULL OR`
`k.ISO_Code IS NULL`

Comment: I did not know you could define the same table with different variables. I will try this and get back to you. Appreciate the input.